# One Regex works, the other doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for data that looks like `abc/def`. There may be whitespace around the text anywhere, so all of the following would be valid: `abc__/_def` or `__abc/__def__`. (Using underscores to visualize spaces.)

I came up with this regular expression:

```
(?<=\s*)abc\s*\/\s*def(?=\s*|^)
```

This works to find matches. I only recently picked up look-ahead and tried this expression to exclude spaces around `/` from the match (so `abc__/_def` would produce a match `abc/def`):

```
(?<=\s*)abc(?=\s*)\/(?=\s*)def(?=\s*|^)
```

This expression doesn't work - I obviously misunderstand something about look-aheads. Can someone explain the difference between the two expressions? (Is it even possible what I'm trying to do? After reading the Regex documentation I thought it was but maybe I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match returned by any .NET regex is a contiguous substring of the original string. This means that you cannot get rid of the space around the "/" character. You can get rid of the outer spaces though.

A good approach would be to match `abc` and `def` using named groups and extract that information using

```
Match m = ...;
var part1 = m.Groups["part1"].Value;
var part2 = m.Groups["part2"].Value;
```

Try this: `^\s*(?<part1>\w+)\s*/\s*(?<part2>\w+)\s*$`

Oftentimes the regex is more natural with named groups and without lookaround.

Comment: Yes, I thought of using groups but someone in another question said using groups was very expensive and should be avoided and look-aheads and look-behinds were much better. I'm familiar with groups but not with look-ahead and look-behind.

Comment: @xxbbcc "Expensive" is very relative. If you need performance, don't use regex in the first place! Also, like I said, you cannot use lookaround to get rid of the spaces anyway. It is impossible for the reason I stated.

Answer (score 1):

Look aheads and the like are used when you try to find something and also exclude it from the result.

if there are whitespaces between the slash and abc for example the lookahead would find them, however it can not select the whitespaces as the result since you excluded them. there is no continuous string that would match your expression so no string is selected.

You wanted to exclude the whitespaces from the selection and as far as i know you can not do that.

you could just select the abc if you wanted.

```
(?<=\s*)abc(?=(\s*\/\s*def(\s*|^)))
```

But you cant spread your selection around different areas.

If you have to filter your selection afterwards i recommand using a stringbuilder and iterate through the result (for speed reasons) like that.

```
    public Boolean TryRegexMatchRemovedWhiteSpace(string input, string expr, out String matched)
    {

        Match m = Regex.Match(input, expr);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder(m.Value.Length);
            foreach (var c in m.Value)
            {
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {
                    r.Append(c);
                }
            }
            matched = r.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            matched = "";
        }
        return m.Success;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll just use groups - I thought it's possible to do this using look-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it looks ahead, but does not include it when it tries to match. so, if you use

**abc(?=\s*)**

it will match 
**abc**
or **abc___**

but the match groups[0] is 'abc' for both cases.

So, your second regex will match abc/def only, but not abc__/_def

reader

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. I see `abc` would be matched but then it's followed by a look-ahead. The match shouldn't include the whitespace that's found by the look-ahead. According to usr's explanation this wouldn't work anyway because the match must be contignous.

Comment: my understand is: abc(?=\s*) matches 'abc' or 'abc__', but the match's groups[0] does not include the __ in the second case. It is because of the look-ahead. That's why in your case **abc(?=\s*)\/(?=\s*)def(?=\s*|^)**

Comment: sorry, was interrupted, and could not edit last comment anymore. here is an example: ** string t = "abc/def"; Regex reg = new Regex(@"abc(?=\s*)\/"); Match mt = reg.Match(t);  Debug.WriteLine(mt.Success); ** It is a match, but if t = "abc__/def"; (__ is space) it is not. It is because the Match does not include the look-ahead.